# Heroku deployment error - 'We're sorry, but something went wrong"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deployment

I'm getting the error "We're sorry, but something went wrong" when I navigate to my heroku app after deployment. These are the logs from after running `git push heroku master` and then from after running `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Any advice would be much appreciated, as I'm very stuck here and I'm so close to having something up online. Thanks!

```
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:15:59] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.251058+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.251058+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.251058+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:15:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.251058+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:15:59] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-09-27T03:15:59.250881+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.25105
8+00:00 app[web.1]:     bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-09-27T03:15:59.251058+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-09-27T03:15:59.573484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10413 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-09-27T03:16:00.526665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-09-27T03:16:02.896941+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:16:02] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
2013-09-27T03:16:02.892943+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:16:02] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-09-27T03:16:02.897429+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:16:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=10413
2013-09-27T03:16:03.223457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:03 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:10413
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:03 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.438096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-09-27T03:16:19.959728+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: Awaiting client
2013-09-27T03:16:19.993002+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-09-27T03:16:21.287810+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-27T03:16:23.769398+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: Process exited with status 0
2013-09-27T03:16:23.781951+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: State changed from up to complete
2013-09-27T03:16:24.450472+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:24 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:24.450472+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:24 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.527866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55ms status=500 bytes=706
2013-09-27T03:16:24.573935+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-09-27T03:16:25.628352+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:25 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:25.628352+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:25 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.160724+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=339ms status=500 bytes=706
2013-09-27T03:12:57.743462+00:00 heroku[run.5279]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-27T03:16:25.645210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=706
2013-09-27T03:16:14.901595+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jackerman09@gmail.com
2013-09-27T03:19:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-27T03:20:21.685120+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5a25d1e by jackerman09@gmail.com
2013-09-27T03:20:21.740188+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by jackerman09@gmail.com
2013-09-27T03:20:22+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-09-27T03:20:25.654702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]: 
[2013-09-27 03:20:26] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:26] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-09-27T03:20:27.106260+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45016 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-09-27T03:20:28.127830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-09-27T03:20:29.833226+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=45016
2013-09-27T03:20:29.833042+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-09-27T03:20:29.833042+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:29] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
2013-09-27T03:20:30.342155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up




$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2103

$ heroku logs

2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:10413
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2013-09-27T03:16:03.823477+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:03 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.145839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.438096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-09-27T03:16:19.959728+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: Awaiting client
2013-09-27T03:16:19.993002+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-09-27T03:16:21.287810+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-27T03:16:23.769398+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: Process exited with status 0
2013-09-27T03:16:23.781951+00:00 heroku[run.8653]: State changed from up to complete
2013-09-27T03:16:24.450472+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:24 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:24.450472+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:24 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.495722+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:24.527866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55ms status=500 bytes=706
2013-09-27T03:16:24.573935+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-09-27T03:16:25.628352+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:25 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:25.628352+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:16:25 +0000
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:16:25.641704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:16:04.160724+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=339ms status=500 bytes=706
2013-09-27T03:12:57.743462+00:00 heroku[run.5279]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-27T03:16:25.645210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=706
2013-09-27T03:16:14.901595+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jackerman09@gmail.com
2013-09-27T03:19:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-27T03:20:21.685120+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5a25d1e by jackerman09@gmail.com
2013-09-27T03:20:21.740188+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by jackerman09@gmail.com
2013-09-27T03:20:22+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-09-27T03:20:25.654702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:26] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:26] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vend
or/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476250+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-09-27T03:20:26.476460+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-09-27T03:20:27.106260+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45016 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-09-27T03:20:28.127830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-09-27T03:20:29.833226+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=45016
2013-09-27T03:20:29.833042+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-09-27T03:20:29.833042+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-09-27 03:20:29] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
2013-09-27T03:20:30.342155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-27T03:22:08.966343+00:00 heroku[run.2103]: Awaiting client
2013-09-27T03:22:09.015540+00:00 heroku[run.2103]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-09-27T03:22:10.380038+00:00 heroku[run.2103]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-27T03:22:14.044020+00:00 heroku[run.2103]: Process exited with status 0
2013-09-27T03:22:14.061930+00:00 heroku[run.2103]: State changed from up to complete
2013-09-27T03:22:02.468822+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jackerman09@gmail.com
2013-09-27T03:22:20.272871+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:22:20 +0000
2013-09-27T03:22:20.272871+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-09-27T03:22:20.272871+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2013-09-27T03:22:20.272871+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:45016
2013-09-27T03:22:20.272871+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.204.243.201 at 2013-09-27 03:22:20 +0000
2013-09-27T03:22:20.272871+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-09-27T03:22:20.829092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=104ms service=569ms status=500 bytes=706
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass):
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:5:in `home'
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:22:20.811256+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-27T03:22:21.056314+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=guarded-dawn-5794.herokuapp.com fwd="69.204.243.201" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Whether do you have any exceptions while running your app in local

Comment: I am using SQLite3 in development and PG in production. My app runs smoothly when running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you need to be concerned about is the following: NoMethodError (undefined method `player_1' for nil:NilClass)

While you have migrated your database, the data from your local database will not be in the production database. The method, player_1, is being called on something that is nil, most likely something that is not nil on your local database since you would have seen the error locally before deploying.

Building a seeds file at db/seeds.rb will enable you to get data into your production database by simply running:

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

In the seeds file you can create rows in the database tables just like you would elsewhere in your app:

```
@user = User.create(username: 'ryanfrancis', email: 'ryan@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')
@user.save
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually just did this, and the error message changed to 'The page you are looking for doesn't exist.' I am able to navigate to myapp.com/players (another page) which shows, but the root page is not displaying. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Did you have the page loading correctly on your localhost? Are there any conditionals in the action associated with your root page that could cause the app to redirect to another page?

Comment: It works fine locally, and no there are no conditionals. I remember reading somewhere that Heroku doesn't like root to: in routes.rb, but it's ok with root, however, I made the change, and it's still not working, so I'm still stuck.

Comment: On heroku.com, add the papertrail add-on to your app which will enable you to see the server logs. Initiate the error again and see if you can find a more descriptive error message through the logs.